# Do not get return value in controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get last inserted id in controller.

For that I am making one function in model. that was as below:

```
    function _insert($data){
    $table = $this->get_table();
    $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    $inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id(); 
    return $inserted_id;
}
```

Now how to use this return value in controller?

Comment: try: $this->db->last_query(); see if the query is being executed correctly

Comment: But there is a more than one query in model.

Answer (score 2):

in controller

```
$last_id=$this->model_name->_insert($data);
```

so your last id is saved in $last_id variable.